# making absolute child absolute to an other relative continer

Tags: html, css

I have a big container, and inside container mini boxes these boxes has a relative position and inside the relative children absolute once I wanna make it absolute to the big container not to mini boxes

```
<pre>

<div class="container">
 <div class="relativeChild">
  <div class="absoluteChild"></div>`
 </div>
</div>

</pre>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this is impossible, the closest parent having relative/absolute position will be the parent of the inner child.

Comment: so is there any way to get the result i want ?!

Comment: I've ever wanted to achieve the same thing in some cases, however I think you can always solve your problem another way than just having to achieve this **impossible** thing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shoud move your div to the main container. It must be the children of the main container.

Comment: I can't it is a div created dynamically with jQuery 

and it must be inside the relative child